# Would self-fitting clothes be a great innovation for a future civilization or would it be a passing fad?

Tags: technology, technological-development, clothing

Self-fitting clothes sound cool but I can't help but feel that they wouldn't last long and would soon become impractical and just a passing fad. What are the benefits and drawbacks to self fitting clothes?

Comment: This question seems primarily opinion based. Opinion based questions aren't allowed. I'd suggest you check out the how to ask page.<https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask>

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate some more on what you mean with "self fitting" clothes.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be quantified. It might be impractical, it might not be. It might be a passing fad, it might be not. If you're writing a story, I suggest you think about the implication of each scenario and go with the most exciting one.

Comment: Edited to make it a more defined question.

Comment: There might be a good question in here. But in order to be a good question you would have to describe more about what that "self fitting clothing" can and can not do and how hard it is to make compared to regular clothing.

Comment: @Braydon You should be careful about formatting links. The link you used doesn't work because there is a ">" at the end that is interpreted as part of the link. You can use the formatted link syntax in comments like `[This is text](this/is/a/link)`. Or you can use the [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/352819) like for example `[help]` or `[edit]` or `[tour]`. In this case `[ask]` would yield [ask].

Answer (score 3):

Presuming the self-fitting feature of clothing was inexpensive, actually worked, and eventually the cost of such a feature was not noticeable to consumers; they would become ubiquitous. IRL many wealthy people that can afford tailors do use them, whether people "notice" their clothes are fitted or not.

Fitting can make a garment you like available, particularly if the only available pre-made sizes are all either too baggy in some places or too tight or stretched in another.

That means self-fitting is a valuable feature for ***both*** producers and consumers: It increases the market size for producers, and increases the range of styles for consumers.

There is no reason to think it would be any less popular than other similar innovations; like color-fastness, washability, non-shrinking, stain-resistance, and so on. Even if it were noticeably more expensive, it might attract an intermediate market between the lower middle class and those that can routinely afford more expensive custom tailoring.